# SQL query taking extensive amounts of time

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble with speed in the following query

```
Select * 
from Table1 
join table2 on table1.key = table2.key
where table2.code IN ('Code1','Code2',...,'Code18') 
  and table1.accountnumber in ('account1','account2',...,'account30000')
```

EDIT: Yes there is an ON in my join i apologize for being sloppy and leaving it out in my original question

It takes about 8 seconds with a total of 3 million rows and 18 codes and 4-5 accounts. However, my true data set is about 80 million+ rows and there can be hundreds of thousands of accounts. I cant seem to figure out how to speed this up and would appreciate some help. The account numbers are generated from a file that can have anywhere from 4 numbers to tens of thousands. but the codes are hard coded and never change.

Comment: Hmm... `Ctrl+F` "index" --> `0 of 0`

Comment: are you really wanting to create an SQL query that returns 80 million rows?  If so it is going to take some time that is a lot of records.

Comment: Where's the `ON` for your `JOIN`?

Comment: @GoatCO I just looked it up. Apparently you CAN leave out the ON

Comment: You're obviously  not going to hard code your codes or account numbers so please share with us the ACTUAL code you're using

Comment: How are you identifying the list of `accountnumber` values to use?  Do you want to bring back every combination of records that meet your `WHERE` criteria?

Comment: why are you joining these tables, it doesn't do anything.  If they do in fact have a field you can join them on I suggest putting it in there.  That will likely increase the efficiency at least some.

Comment: When you join two tables without an `ON` condition, you're declaring that your result set should start with all possible combinations of the data from `table1` and `table2`. So, if `table1` has 80M rows and `table2` has 100K rows, you're going to be scanning though 8 terarows to isolate the rows you want. Can this possibly be correct???

Comment: Do you have indexes on table2.code and table1.accountnumber? Have you tried adding an ON clause for your join?

Comment: 'account2',...,'account30000' are there 30k items in your `in` statement?

Comment: @mgrenier There are about 80 million rows total i have to filter through to potentially match. Will most time return less than 10k rows.

Comment: @GoatCO I do actually join on a unique column sloppy on my part fair enough. And yes I want to bring back all combinations that meet my where criteria.

Comment: @JoePhilllips actually the Codes are hard coded the account numbers i generate the string from a csv file given to me which can vary in length from 4 lines to 5000 so do you really want those 5000 numbers that dont mean anything to you?

Comment: @castis Yes there can be 30000 items in my IN statement.

Comment: @JonathanCrowe I am restricted and not allowed to add indexes but yes that is the first thing I am looking to test when I can get someone to put it in.

Comment: I suppose dumping the 30k records into their own table, and joining against them isn't feasible?  or are the 30k values dynamically generated?  If nothing else, that'd at least clean up your query...

Comment: @user2755680 Your best bet is to add indexes on those two fields and see how much that helps. What you are doing is an inherently expensive operation

Comment: @user2366842 dynamically generated

Comment: In that case, indexing is going to be about the only way to fix it.  Any time you involve an `IN` operator, especially on an unindexed column, it's a very intensive operation, and the query will usually run for a while.

Comment: @JonathanCrowe Ya i had a feeling that was going to be the answer just didnt know if there was some other way to refactor this that is faster. guess ill just hope the indexes fix it. Thanks

Comment: @user2366842 Ya that was my guess at the only way to speed it up but figured may also be a way to refactor this to speed it up.

Comment: Probably want to put indexes on both code and account number if at all possible...

Comment: Since you generate your filter data e.g. ('Code1','Code2') to put dinamically on your where condition you could create a temporary table add those filters and add another join operation. It will be much faster then an IN operator !

Comment: @JorgeCampos Alright Ill give this a try. Thanks for the suggestion this is the kind of thing i was looking for from the beginning.

Comment: Ok, glad to help. Let us know if it really help, then I will add an elaborated answer with it :)

Comment: Good call on the temp table.  Not sure why I didn't think of that, as I use it from time to time myself.  Guess I was asleep at the wheel.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Since there are so many records temp tables only allow 1000 rows to be inserted at once. I need to run 8 inserts that take longer than just running the query using an IN. Good idea though. Ill have to remember that

Comment: Then create two table with just those fields and use it. The process will insert on the tables do the query and delete. Also the IN statement is constrained by an mysql configuration so, maybe you  will have an error because of the quantity of string on that IN statement. And why 8 inserts if you have just two columns to filter?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's look at what you want to do:

- Filter `table1` by `key` and `accountnumber`
- Filter `table2` by `key` and `code`
- Note: filtering by `key` is bounded because tables depend on each other by this column
- Note: filtering by other columns don't intersect with each other so can be done independently (e.g. before joining by `key`)

So, you can do:

- Index `key` column in both tables. But if tables are huge and filtering by `key` is rare operation it'll be bad idea. I just mean **creating index on `key` column may be bad, it depends on your database**.
- Due to the last paragraph of the list above, you can filter before join. So you can create temp tables with pre filtered data.
- Since your `in` statements can be very long, it'll be very stupid to not store it in temp table and then join with it instead of `in`. I mean store all your `code` which are supposed to be in `in` statement and then do filtering by joining with this temp table.
- Index `code` and `accountnumber` also is a good idea.

Overall you need to test and research how big are your tables and `in` statements and what's better - to create indexes on `key` and get followed order:

1. *global step before*: create index on `key` column. [*It isn't required. Only if it's good in your case!*]
2. join by `key`
3. store result in temp table
4. create index on `code`/`accountnumber` in this temp table. [*It isn't required. Only if it's good in your case!*]
5. create temp table for `code`/`accountnumber` `in` statement values (with primary keys on particular columns). [*It isn't required. Only if it's good in your case!*]
6. filter by `code`/`accountnumber` by joining tables

or :

1. *global step before*: create index on `code`/`accountnumber` column in your `table`/`table2`. [*It isn't required. Only if it's good in your case!*]
2. create temp table for `code`/`accountnumber` `in` statement values (with primary keys on particular columns). [*It isn't required. Only if it's good in your case!*]
3. separately filter by `code`/`accountnumber` by joining pairs of tables => two temp tables -  `filtered_table1` and `filtered_table2` with `key` column as primary key
4. join them by `key`

I hope you got the idea of possible optimizations. Further you just need to test these possible ways, I think.

Hope it helps!